# Difference between desktops (lubuntu) qt, gtk?

Tags: lubuntu, gtk, qt, minimal-install

Upon installing Ubuntu, I get to choose what more to install, but what's the difference between:

> **Lubuntu minimal installation**
>
> Lubuntu desktop
>
> **Lubuntu minimal installation GTK part**
>
> Lubuntu desktop GTK part
>
> **Lubuntu minimal installation Qt part**
>
> Lubuntu desktop Qt part

I guess those in bold isn't desktop environment.
But, what's Qt, GTK?

I'm going to run a server, who demanded a web browser, (to verify stuff against other servers) but otherwise I'm just after a quick and lightweight system (I ran this server precious on Ubuntu mini, but Facebook required the browser for verifications (got id-challenged 13 times during the last 48hours so I'm giving up on pure terminal system.)

*I'm aware that's there's some questions about this already, but they have a few years on then, things do evolve..*

Comment: GTK was originally the GIMP Tookit, it was adopted as GIMP + GNOME Toolkit (GTK+) which today is called GTK.  The only thing in last five years is the dropping of the + in GTK.   Qt predates GTK and hasn't changed in far longer; except versions increase.  Current GTK work is on GTK4 (but GTK3 is still seen as stable), Current Qt is Qt5.  Qt4 is no depreciated, GTK2 will soon be deprecated.

Comment: Little has changed since mid-90s; outside of versions. You mention Lubuntu but are not specific about Lubuntu in the question (Lubuntu was GTK+2 or GTK+ version 2 today just written as GTK2); Lubuntu started switching from LXDE (GTK+2) to LXQt in 2015 which has now happened; ie. modern Lubuntu uses LXQt (Qt5). Lubuntu 18.04 LTS still uses LXDE as LXQt wasn't deemed ready in time.

Comment: Providing release details would also be helpful, for some releases LXDE would be my choice (ie. before Lubuntu switched to LXQt), but for other releases I'd avoid LXDE (many parts are no longer in Ubuntu repositories as GTK+2 is being dropped) and use only LXQt.   Your release is the most critical part of your decision (plus upgrade wishes)/

Comment: I would base decision on your unstated release, and upgrade paths, but that is just my opinion.   LXDE has no upgrade path beyond 18.04 LTS without re-install (possible yes, but unsupported due to problems; doco was written for it, but it was never published; still can be found; though can't recall if it's visible to public as I might be seeing stuff that is Lubuntu members only)

Comment: Another thought that may interest you (more historical bs); Qt is used by Android apps on phones/tablets, is used by windows apps, the company that owns Qt provides free access to GNU/Linux projects with keyboard/mouse. GTK+ was used by GNOME because FSF didn't like a company owning the toolkit used by 'free' software thus the quick 'fix' or modifying GIMP Toolkit (GTK) to become GTK+ (now GTK again).  You won't find GTK+ apps outside of GNU/Linux (some BSD) though

Answer (score 0):

Lubuntu comes either with [LXQT](https://lxqt.org/) or with  [LXDE](https://lxde.org/). These are different Desktop environments.

Comment: Legacy Lubuntu uses LXDE; it's no longer developed; and the Lubuntu manual (https://manual.lubuntu.me/) today only refers to LXQt (or many call it modern Lubuntu).  LXDE was in the past with Lubuntu's focus almost exclusively on LXQt.

Comment: I'm after a really lightweight, but still can use the basic apps

Comment: @joBe it should really be both fine for a server setup. LXDE is older and maybe more "mature".

Comment: @Bruni and LXDE is qt or Gtk?

Comment: @ JoBe LXDE is GTK

Comment: LXDE is GTK2, all GTK2 support is *slowly* in the process of being removed from Debian/Ubuntu repositories (except 18.04 & before).  GTK4 is being developed; thus old is now GTK3 (as used in current Ubuntu releases) thus why GTK2 is going going & soon gone.  (*Qt4 is also being removed; currently there is more flak about the Qt4 losses as apps disappear.. GTK2 is behind Qt4's removal*)

Comment: I've downloaded the Ubuntu 18.04 LTS "Bionic Beaver" mini,  which GTK/Qt are on the release?

Comment: Bionic beaver uses LXDE (GTK) as its base.